# error decorators-legacy. Not vorking mobx+react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, mobx

[image]

I want use React js+Mobx but I'm getting an error

ERROR
./src/stores/Todo.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users...example path\Todo.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (9:5):

```
   [enter image description here][1]
```

Versions
    "mobx": "^5.15.2",
    "mobx-react": "^6.1.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Babel plugin [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators) in your babel config.

- For this you should install it as a dependency, from npm.

`npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators -DE`

- Then add the following lines to your babel config under plugins.

```
//...
plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
      {
        'legacy': true
      }
    ],
// ...
]
```

Comment: thanks . I solved the problem this way:
```
const {
  override,
  addDecoratorsLegacy,
  disableEsLint
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
  // enable legacy decorators babel plugin
  addDecoratorsLegacy(),
  // disable eslint in webpack
  disableEsLint()
);
```